# Urllib3 Connection is timed out only in Azure Devops Build

Tags: python, azure, devops, pipeline, python-unittest

I am using Azure Devops for CI/CD and encountered strange problem today. One of the python unit tests failed due to urllib3 connection time out. Here is the full output:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='goo.gl', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /maps/xxxxx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AE5F442320>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

The strange thing is that; I logged in to build machine (it is a self-hosted Windows machine), tried to run same unit test with same configuration which azure devops build agent uses and test passed. By configuration I mean same conda environment and same Windows user which is "*nt authority\network service*" for azure devops build agent.

So here is the question why it is failing in the pipeline for no reason?

Comment: Does the problem repeat itself? or did it fail just one time?

Comment: It repeats itself.